# Azure application gateway health probe status code

Tags: azure, azure-application-gateway

Is there any specific meaning of each status code returned by the app gateway health probe wheather it is healthy or unhealthy?

Answer (score 1):

In Application Gateway probe configuration you get an option to update the range of status code you would accept as healthy. By default Application gateway will consider the backend as healthy if it receives the status code from 200 -399.

If your application returns 401 and if you think the service is healthy when it is returning 401 and it is just the authorization error, then you can add 401 to the accepted status code. When you do that Application Gateway will consider the backend as healthy when it returns 401 for the Application Gateway probe.